# Forest does not work with De Gruyter template for books and articles

Tags: errors, forest

I'm trying to get the `forest` package to work with the `dgruyter` template for articles and books, but to no avail.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[USenglish]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[small]{dgruyter}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={s sep=10mm, inner sep=0, l=0}
[CP
  [C] 
  [IP [I] 
    [VP [V]] 
  ] 
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Typesetting this gives rise to an endless stream of error messages, and no typeset.

Comment: *Which* error do you get? Only the first is usually important, but the exact text of that message matters. Also where can we find `dgruyter.sty`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [DeGruyter package](https://www.degruyter.com/dg/page/production-for-authors) ([direct link zip file](https://www.degruyter.com/fileasset/pdfs/AUTH_DG_LaTeX-Template.zip)) naughtily redefines all tabulars to use `booktabs`, and this messes with TikZ `align=center` which the `linguistics` library of `forest` uses.

The relevant error as cfr mentions in the comments is the first one, and this clearly implicates `booktabs` since `\bottomrule` is a `booktabs` macro:

```
Misplaced \noalign.
\bottomrule ->\noalign 
                       {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \@aboverulesep =\aboverulesep \global...
l.18 \end{forest}
```

Fortunately, they have also provided a switch to turn it off, `\baretabulars`, so we can prepend that to every `forest` environment:

```
\documentclass[USenglish]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[small]{dgruyter}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\AtBeginEnvironment{forest}{\baretabulars}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={s sep=10mm, inner sep=0, l=0}
[CP
  [C] 
  [IP [I] 
    [VP [V]] 
  ] 
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Can somebody please provide a link for the `.sty` this question is about?

Comment: @cfr I added a link.